# Name of an operation on graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, terminology

Let $G$ and $H$ be two possibly directed, non necessarily simple, vertex-labelled graphs with respective adjacency matrices $A_G$ and $A_H$ and $V(G)=V(H)$.

1) What is the name of the graph $M$ with adjacency matrix $A_M=A_HA_G$?

2) In the unlikely event that I am the first to think about using that operation, which symbols should I NOT use to denote it in order to avoid confusion with [other graph products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_product)?

**UPDATE:** I have now asked this question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49233/name-of-an-operation-on-graphs) as well.

Comment: Note that the product of two 0-1 matrices is not necessarily a 0-1 matrix.

Comment: @J.M: That's okay. Positive integer entries correspond to more than one edge joining the appropriate vertices.

Comment: J. M. is indeed right, and I'll have to choose my graphs carefully. However, I don't think it affects my question, as Jim Conant points out.

Comment: You are certainly not the first to think about using this operation, in the sense that it is a natural operation and will surely occur to anyone who takes adjacency matrices seriously (for example I have used it in certain combinatorial proofs).  But if it has a name, I don't know that you'll find it in the graph theory literature, since most graph theorists don't seem to care about directed graphs with more than one edge between vertices.

Comment: You better have the same number of vertices in G and H for the product to be defined. If they are on the same vertices and you make the matrix not (0,1) but reflecting the number of edges between vertices, then I think the product matrix will be the number of paths from a vertex to another that start with a step in G and then have a step in H.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is known as *Graph Squaring*. See also [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphPower.html).

Comment: No, it's not.  When you take powers of graphs you ignore the multiplicity of the edges.  The formula given in the article is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As described in Brualdi and Cvetkovic's [Combinatorial Approach to Matrix Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=pwx6t8QfZU8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=combinatorial+approach+to+matrix+theory),  rather than associating a directed graph in the usual way to a matrix, it's more natural to associate the **König digraph** for the purposes of thinking about matrix multiplication.  For an $m \times n$ non-negative integer matrix $A$, the König digraph is a bipartite digraph with vertex classes $X$ (with $n$ elements) and $Y$ (with $m$ elements) such that the number of edges from $x \in X$ to $y \in Y$ is $A_{yx}$.  Composition of matrices then corresponds to "plugging" one digraph into another, and whatever purpose you want to multiply adjacency matrices for, I think it will be more natural (or at least equivalent) phrased in this language instead.

What I've described is a category whose objects are the non-negative integers $[n], n \ge 0$ and where a morphism from $[n]$ to $[m]$ is a collection of arrows from an $n$-element set to an $m$-element.  This category is a certain refinement of the category of finite sets and [relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) and is a very natural setting for certain combinatorial arguments (as well as for, as the book says, a combinatorial approach to matrix theory).  I don't know if it has a name, though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be helpful... from position that $M$ is a hypergraph, value of matrix element $A_M(i,j)$ seems to be equal to the number of edges from vertex i to vertex j with length 2 (minus edges from j to i). But I'm not sure, if $A_M$ is adjacency matrix for hypergraph $M$... Especially after googling ["hypergraph adjacency matrices"](http://books.google.ru/books?id=DWZc9Ti_vBwC&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=hypergraph+adjacency+matrix+definition&source=bl&ots=2R8o1vC0Z3&sig=h-2ubx2ytHCYCatkQ8YlG12mWtA&hl=ru&ei=8RX9TN_eH4eXOp_nwdQK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&sqi=2&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=hypergraph%20adjacency%20matrix%20definition&f=false)